# How to send and receive commands from a UDP network server via .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, udp

I have a UDP server, which is a scale, that is connected to the network. It is listening to any data being sent to it and response with a data back to the client, depending on what command is sent to it. I was able to test this with YAT, a software used to test serial communication.

Testing UDP Connection on YAT:

[image: Testing UDP Connection on YAT]

I want to create a C# (.NET Core) console application that does the same thing. Basically, I want to connect to the UDP server (scale), send commands to it, and receive the data from it. But it doesn't seem to work at the receiving end.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ipAddress = "10.130.12.81";
        var portNumber = 2102;
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), portNumber);

        try
        {
            var client = new UdpClient();
            client.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            if (client != null)
            {
                var weigh = "\nW\r";
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(weigh);

                client.Send(data, data.Length);
                var receivedData = client.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received Data: {receivedData}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, it is able to connect and send the data, but sits idle at the client.Receive line, waiting for a message to be sent.

The second time around, I created 2 console apps:

**Sender**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var udpClient = new UdpClient();
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_ipAddress), _port);
        udpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint);

        var msgSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("W\n");
        udpClient.Send(msgSent, msgSent.Length);
    }
```

**Receiver**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var udpServer = new UdpClient(2102);
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port);

        var msgReceived = udpServer.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
        Console.Write("received data from: " + ipEndPoint.ToString());
    }
```

I tried to run and send messages several times, but no luck. Not sure if I am missing anything. I'll keep hammering away at this; if this doesn't work I'll try using the Socket class instead of UdpClient.

Comment: Be careful when using UDP. UDP does not guarantee delivery of packets. Because you can not assume that the send will work, you maybe have to send and receive separately.

Comment: Please read the "Examples" section carefully, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive?view=netframework-4.8 If you just want to send something and don't expect a response, don't call `Receive`.